# File containing 1s and 0s to binary file

Tags: file, binary

I have very long sequence of ones and zeros in a file looking like this
[image] etc, each 32bits should represent one (32 bit large) integer. Is there a way to transform this mess of 1s and 0s to a binary file containing **x** *(filesize/32)* subsequential 32bit integers?

These numbers are generated (from RNG) and I would then like to use this binary file for further analysis - but it has to be binary file - not text file containing ones and zeros.

Does this even make sense? I hope so.

Answer (score 1):

Create a loop that looks at 8 digits each iteration. In an inner loop, use bitshifts to string the binary digits together. Then write the resulting byte to a binary file.

Pseudocode:

```
for(int i = 0; i < file.length; i += 8) {
    byte b = 0b00000000;
    for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        if(readChar(i+j) == '1')
            b |= 1 << j; // bit-wise OR and bitshift
    }
    writeByte(b);
}
```